# Disable auto tabs when putting your first comment in a yaml files with VIM editor?

Tags: vim, vimrc

Example of text **before** changes:

```
First line
Second line
Third line
```

**When you put a comment on a line it will auto tab once that line.**

**This happens every time you switch from ESCAPE mode to INSERT mode for the first comment.**

Example of text **after** adding your first comment ( # )

```
First line
     #Second line
Third line
```

What is the option to put in **.vimrc** to disable this behavior?
There is no article I could find on google that talks about this topic.
Thank you!

Comment: You should at least [edit] your question to tell potential answerers what `filetype` this is.  Because the immediate response as it stands is that the behaviour described in the question as it stands _does not happen_ in a simple new buffer, and the premise of the question is wrong.  https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/17667/incorrect-auto-indent-bash/17716#comment30325_17667

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is caused by `0#` being part of the [`'indentkeys'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html?#%27indentkeys%27) for the YAML filetype. You can disable this behaviour by adding the following to, say, `~/.vim/after/indent/yaml.vim`:

```
set indentkeys-=0#
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to @muru's answer, you can achieve the same effect by placing this in your configuration (`.vimrc` for Vim, or `init.vim` for NeoVim):

```
augroup filetype_yaml
  autocmd!
  autocmd BufEnter *.yaml,*.yml
  \ setlocal indentkeys-=0#
augroup END
```

Comment: Or, the one-liner: `autocmd BufEnter *.yaml,*.yml :set indentkeys-=0#`